# Is this a perfectly rigorous proof for "if and only if"? Any missing bits to achieve perfect rigor?

Tags: proof-writing

*Note:  my goal is maximum mathematical rigor.*

The toy problem here is (from [{Spivak's Calculus book}'s 1st chapter]'s problems):

- *Prove that, if $b,d\ne 0$, then $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$ if and only if $ad = bc$.*
- Allowed axioms are only:  additive association/inverse/identity, multiplicative association/inverse/identity, and distributive property of addition and multiplication.

Now, what puzzles me is:  how would my proof be different if there was no "*if and only if*" phrase?

## Below is my proving attempt:

First let's rewrite the problem in a language closer to the axioms:

- Prove $ab^{-1} = cd^{-1}$ if and only if $ad = bc$ (of
  course, $b,d\ne 0$).

*Proof---* By multiplying both sides by $bd$:

$$
ab^{-1}bd = cd^{-1}bd
$$

By [axiom mul assotition]

$$
a(b^{-1}b)d = c(d^{-1}d)b
$$

By [axiom mul inverse]:

$$
a(1)d = c(1)b
$$

By [axiom mul identity]:

$$
ad = cb
$$

$\blacksquare$

## My questions

Is my proof above adequate to show "if" (way forward) and "and only if" (way back) properties?

If *maximum rigor* is to sought for my proof, should I add any extra wordings there to signify that my proof is actually proving the "iff" (both ways) and not only "if" (forward)?  E.g. should I reverse the proof backwards to show that it's both ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof assumes, from the start, that, given three real numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$, with $c\neq0$,$$a=b\iff ac=bc.$$Perhaps that you could prove it.

Besides, after multiplying both sides by $bd$, what you should get is $(ab^{-1})(bd)=(cd^{-1})(bd)$. Only then can you use associativity to prove what you want to prove. And note that you have used the commutativity of the multiplication, when you went from $cd^{-1}bd$ to $c(d^{-1}d)b$ .

Comment: Thanks.  What do you mean by "perhaps that you could prove it"?  Are you implying that I did not prove it, but I could?   I'm also confused, are you also saying that my proof is perfect rigor, except for only one fault as I misapplied the multiplication?

Comment: I meant that your proof is incomplete and that, in order to be complete you should prove that statement. And, yes, there was that small fail that I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks.  Could you please also explain how is my proof assuming that $a = b \iff ac = bc$?  To me it seems that I am just starting from the question ($ab^{-1} = cd^{-1}$) and playing with it until I get $ad=cb$.  The only errors that I did that I understand is that misused multiplication and skipped commutativity.

Comment: At the first step, when you claim that $ab^{-1}=cd^{-1}\iff ab^{-1}bd=cd^{-1}bd$.

Comment: Oh, you mean I should assume form those axioms that multiplying both sides of the equation by the same value (i.e. $bd$) would work, as this by itself needs a proof?

Comment: Almost. You should prove that $a=b\iff ac=bc$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I should _not_ assume (typo; can't edit now).  Was your "Almost" only because of my typos (forgetting _"not"_ there)?  --- Is the proof only substituting $a$ into $b$, so $ac=bc$ becomes $ac=ac$?

Comment: Substituting $a$ into $b$ only proves that $a=b\implies ac=bc$. In order to prove that $ac=bc\implies a=b$, you should do$$ac=bc\implies(ac)c^{-1}=(bc)c^{-1}\iff a(cc^{-1})=b(cc^{-1})\iff a=b.$$

Comment: Isn't this cyclic?  E.g. as you tried to prove the theorem: $a=b \implies ac=bc$, you had to use the theorem in step $ac=bc \implies (ac)c^{-1} = (bc)c^{-1}$ (which seems to me to at least assume that $a=b \to ac=bc$).  No? Or am I totally missing the point of this whole discussion?  :)

Comment: No. $a=b\implies ac=bc$ is *trivial*, in the sense that it works for each and every operation we can possibly imagine. But $ac=bc\implies a=b$ is not of the same nature. It works in goroups, not not for every conceivable operation.